PKCS Session doesn't persist on Ubuntu 24.04 when doing other token authentication
How to reproduce:
# Initialize PKCS11 token (any method is fine)
ssh-add -t 72000 -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
# Token works as expected

# Attempt login to token using some other tool
pkcs11-tool -l -L

# 1st token session is now broken

The correct behavior, and what Ubuntu seemed to do until 24.04, is for the original session to continue to work, but, in 24.04, any login query breaks old sessions.
Does anyone know how to prevent this behavior (i.e. new sessions shouldn't break old sessions) or can anyone assist in debugging what is happening. dmesg doesn't show obvious errors.

Please enable verbose logging for both ssh-add and pkcs11-tool with ssh-add -vv -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so pkcs11-tool -l -L --verbose and  analyze the logs to identify why the first session breaks.
